# The heat kernel in Hermitian bundles over Riemannian manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, laplacian, heat-equation

In "Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators" by Berline, Getzler and Vergne, the authors construct a (unique) heat kernel associated to any generalized Laplacian in a vector bundle over a Riemannian manifold.

> Could you please point me to texts doing the same kind of construction (not necessarily using densities) in vector bundles over *arbitrary* (i.e. not necessarily compact anymore) Riemannian manifolds for the connection Laplacian?

I am mostly interested in the clear definition of the object and the statement of its basic properties. Do the positivity and minimality properties of the heat kernel on functions have analogous properties in bundles?

Comment: The construction of heat kernel is something *local* since Laplacian is defined only locally. Thus the construction you learned can be extended to the interior of any manifolds. For the construction of heat kernel over manifold with boundary, there are many references available. One thing you may clarify is that you probably need some boundary condition imposed on the metric. Otherwise the Laplacian on the buondary is technically no different from the Laplacian on a different submanifold.

Comment: @Bombyxmori: Thank you, but I was looking for a reference, i.e. a text containing all the details from bottom to top. Should I understand your comment as suggesting that such a text might not exist?

Comment: M: There are plenty of such books. One book you can use is Yau and Schoen's book "Lecture on Differential Geometry". A lot of it is on construction of the heat kernel. However I never read the book myself. You may also try Richard Melrose' book "Atiyah Singer Patodi index theorem". Both are very dense and can be hard to read.

Comment: @Bombyxmori: Melrose's construction is for bundles over compact manifolds, then extended to copmpact "b"-manifolds. Yau's and Schoen's construction is for the trivial bundle $M \times \mathbb R$ over a complete manifold with non-zero injectivity radius. None of these is what I want.

Comment: This is actually not entirely true. Melrose's construction can be extended to even worse situation than manifold with boundary, like cusp singularity. I never read Yau and Schoen's book in detail, but I am kind of skeptical if their method is as restrictive as you said.

Comment: @Bombyxmori: Yau and Schoen construct the heat kernel on complete manifolds, assuming the existence of parametrices. Next, they prove this existence in an appendix, where they make the supplementary assumption that the injectivity radius is non-zero - "for simplicity". I hate it when people cut corners "for simplicity". Oh, and they don't deal with bundles, either. It's essentially the "usual" heat kernel, done in less generality - Grigor'yan does it in full generality in his heat kernel book.

Comment: M: I think this is a good point. Others I know pointed out Yau and Schoen had numerous mistakes.